# Set breakpoints for shell script debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am able to successfully run shell scripts and create and configure shell script run configurations in IntelliJ. However, I can't set breakpoints. When I try to put a breakpoint in the gutter or elsewhere as with regular Java debugging, no breakpoint appears. Has anyone had success with this, and if so how?

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.3.6 Community Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell script debugging is supported only by the paid [BashSupport Pro](https://www.bashsupport.com/pro/) plug-in. You would also need the latest IntelliJ IDEA version to use it.

> BashSupport Pro adds advanced features for shell scripts to your
>   JetBrains IDE. You can debug Bash scripts, run bats-core tests and
>   work efficiently with shell scripts.

[image: debug in bashsupport pro]

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder. I cannot upgrade my Intellij as its fixed for my environment.

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy Sorry to hear that, you may want to talk to your admins if you really need this feature, otherwise there is no solution that I can suggest. BashSupport Pro requires IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 or later.